How to Construct Arbitrary Rotations from Discrete Rational Rotations?
One of the most commonly used universal quantum gates sets is the Clifford + T set, containing {CNOT, H, S, T}. However, as S is a $\pi / 2$ rotation about the Z axis of the bloch sphere and as T is a $\pi / 4$ rotation around a bloch sphere, how is an arbitrary Z rotation gate constructed from this universal set? It would seem to me that only rotations by a multiple of $\pi / 4$ around the Z axis would be possible?
For example, how could you construct or approximate a $R_Z(\pi / 3)$ rotation gate solely from the Clifford + T set?

not a bad question but probably better suited for QCSE.

Oh cool, I didn't know that existed, thanks!

I found this post on the QCSE which proves that you can make an irrational angle about some axis from just the discrete gates, because the rotations form the sides of a triangle on a sphere, and the length of the resulting hypotenuse (the net rotation) is irrational. With an irrational gate, you can keep going around the bloch sphere until you happen upon a good approximation of the gate you wish to implement.
However, this doesn't directly give arbitrary rotation about the Z axis, but it is on a 45 degree angle to the z axis, so the gate can be rotated in order to achieve the desired result.
